# Opening zipfile of unsupported compression-type silently returns empty filestream, instead of throwing exception

Tags: python, file-type, python-zipfile

Seem to be knocking my head off a newbie error and I am not a newbie.
I have a 1.2G known-good zipfile *'train.zip'* containing a 3.5G file *'train.csv'*.
I open the zipfile and file itself without any exceptions (no *LargeZipFile*), but the resulting filestream appears to be empty. (UNIX *'unzip -c ...'* confirms it is good)
The file objects returned by Python `ZipFile.open()` are not seek'able or tell'able, so I can't check that.

Python distribution is *2.7.3 EPD-free 7.3-1 (32-bit)* ; but should be ok for large zips. OS is MacOS 10.6.6

```
import csv
import zipfile as zf

zip_pathname = os.path.join('/my/data/path/.../', 'train.zip')
#with zf.ZipFile(zip_pathname).open('train.csv') as z:
z = zf.ZipFile(zip_pathname, 'r', zf.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True) # I tried all permutations
z.debug = 1
z.testzip() # zipfile integrity is ok

z1 = z.open('train.csv', 'r') # our file keeps coming up empty?

# Check the info to confirm z1 is indeed a valid 3.5Gb file...
z1i = z.getinfo(file_name)
for att in ('filename', 'file_size', 'compress_size', 'compress_type', 'date_time',  'CRC', 'comment'):
    print '%s:\t' % att, getattr(z1i,att)
# ... and it looks ok. compress_type = 9 ok?
#filename:  train.csv
#file_size: 3729150126
#compress_size: 1284613649
#compress_type: 9
#date_time: (2012, 8, 20, 15, 30, 4)
#CRC:   1679210291

# All attempts to read z1 come up empty?!
# z1.readline() gives ''
# z1.readlines() gives []
# z1.read() takes ~60sec but also returns '' ?

# code I would want to run is:
reader = csv.reader(z1)
header = reader.next()
return reader
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cause is the combination of:

- this file's compression type is *type 9: Deflate64/Enhanced Deflate* (PKWare's proprietary format, as opposed to the more common type 8)
- and a [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) bug: it will not throw an exception for unsupported compression-types. It used to just [silently return a bad file object](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) [Section 4.4.5 compression method]. Aargh. How bogus. UPDATE: I filed [bug 14313](http://bugs.python.org/issue14313) and it was fixed back in 2012 so it now raises NotImplementedError when the compression type is unknown.

A command-line **Workaround** is to unzip, then rezip, to get a plain *type 8: Deflated*.

[zipfile will throw an exception in 2.7 , 3.2+](http://bugs.python.org/issue14313) I guess zipfile will never be able to actually handle type 9, for legal reasons.
The Python doc makes no mention whatsoever that zipfile cannot [handle other compression types](http://bugs.python.org/issue14313) :(

Comment: do you know how to check the compression type, so you can anticipate the silent failure?

Comment: @MartinTaleski: I filed a bug, they resolved it, and it now raises NotImplementedError when the compression type is unknown. You could `try .. catch` that. EAFP philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

My solution for handling compression types that aren't supported by Python's ZipFile was to rely on a call to 7zip when ZipFile.extractall fails.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import subprocess, sys

def Unzip(zipFile, destinationDirectory):
    try:
        with ZipFile(zipFile, 'r') as zipObj:
            # Extract all the contents of zip file in different directory
            zipObj.extractall(destinationDirectory)
    except:
        print("An exception occurred extracting with Python ZipFile library.")
        print("Attempting to extract using 7zip")
        subprocess.Popen(["7z", "e", f"{zipFile}", f"-o{destinationDirectory}", "-y"])
```

Comment: Cool.  I know this won't work for everyone, but this is a perfect solution for my use case.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Note that passing a string with arguments to the `Popen` constructor fails on POSIX systems, so to make this cross-platform a sequence should be passed instead of a string, e.g. `subprocess.Popen(["7z", "e", f"{zipFile}", f"-o{destinationDirectory}", "-y"])`. See the discussion here https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: Nice. You're assuming `7z` is somewhere on the path, users will probably want to add logic to harden that for `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

Compression type 9 is Deflate64/Enhanced Deflate, which Python's zipfile module doesn't support (essentially [since zlib doesn't support Deflate64](https://zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq40), which zipfile delegates to).

And if smaller files work fine, I suspect this zipfile was created by Windows Explorer: [for larger files Windows Explorer can decided to use Deflate64](https://superuser.com/q/1249267).

(Note that Zip64 is different to Deflate64. Zip64 is supported by Python's zipfile module, and just makes a few changes to how some metadata is stored in the zipfile, but still uses regular Deflate for the compressed data.)

However, [stream-unzip](https://github.com/uktrade/stream-unzip) now supports Deflate64. Modifying its example to read from the local disk, and to read a CSV file as in your example:

```py
import csv
from io import IOBase, TextIOWrapper
import os

from stream_unzip import stream_unzip

def get_zipped_chunks(zip_pathname):
    with open(zip_pathname, 'rb') as f:
       while True:
           chunk = f.read(65536)
           if not chunk:
               break
           yield chunk

def get_unzipped_chunks(zipped_chunks, filename)
    for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks):
        if file_name != filename:
            for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
                pass
            continue
        yield from unzipped_chunks

def to_str_lines(iterable):
    # Based on the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70639580/1319998
    chunk = b''
    offset = 0
    it = iter(iterable)

    def up_to_iter(size):
        nonlocal chunk, offset

        while size:
            if offset == len(chunk):
                try:
                    chunk = next(it)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                else:
                    offset = 0
            to_yield = min(size, len(chunk) - offset)
            offset = offset + to_yield
            size -= to_yield
            yield chunk[offset - to_yield:offset]

    class FileLikeObj(IOBase):
        def readable(self):
            return True
        def read(self, size=-1):
            return b''.join(up_to_iter(float('inf') if size is None or size < 0 else size))

    yield from TextIOWrapper(FileLikeObj(), encoding='utf-8', newline='')

zipped_chunks = get_zipped_chunks(os.path.join('/my/data/path/.../', 'train.zip'))
unzipped_chunks = get_unzipped_chunks(zipped_chunks, b'train.csv')
str_lines = to_str_lines(unzipped_chunks)
csv_reader = csv.reader(str_lines)

for row in csv_reader:
    print(row)
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to stream through the contents without having to hold the entire thing in memory. Unfortunately in my application it turned out to be extremely slow :( ... Finally I decided to use the command line work-around to unzip the file entirely to disk, and then read the unzipped contents.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro Yeah the deflate64 decompression is pure Python https://github.com/michalc/stream-inflate, so it doesn't surprise me that it's slow. I'm sure it could be sped up, but would be a project I suspect...

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is because of lack of support for the Deflate64 algorithm in the Python standard library, there is now a package available named "zipfile-deflate64".

It is still listed as being in an "alpha" phase.  I just started using it yesterday, 2022-07-18, and it did the job for me.

It is very easy to use, as importing it makes it so you can use the zipfile library like you normally would with added support for Deflate64.

[Link to "zipfile-deflate64" package on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/zipfile-deflate64/)

[Link to "zipfile-deflate64" project on GitHub](https://github.com/brianhelba/zipfile-deflate64)

Here is an example of how to use it.  The API is the same as built-in zipfile package:

```
import zipfile_deflate64 as zipfile

tag_hist_path = "path\\to\\your\\zipfile.zip"
parentZip = zipfile.ZipFile(tag_hist_path, mode="r", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED64)
fileNames = [f.filename for f in parentZip.filelist]
memberArchive = parentZip.open(fileNames[0], mode="r")
b = memberArchive.read() #reading all bytes at once, assuming file isn't too big
txt = b.decode("utf-8") #decode bytes to text string
memberArchive.close()
parentZip.close()
```

And here is a more concise and cleaner way to work with such an archive, per @smci recommendation so you don't have to put the effort into managing the stream resources (i.e., closing them) in case of an error:

```
tag_hist_path = "path\\to\\your\\zipfile.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(tag_hist_path, mode="r", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED64) as parentZip:
    for fileNames in parentZip.filelist:
        with parentZip.open(fileNames[0], mode="r") as memberArchive:
            #Do something with each opened zipfile
```

Comment: Neat, can you post actual code showing how you open a Deflate64 zipfile?

Comment: @smci - Sure.  I just added an example usage.

Comment: I'd clean up your code to use [multiple `with` context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024925/create-a-with-block-on-several-context-managers), and PEP-8-compliant names like `parent_zip`, `member_archive`. Also, I'd explicitly iterate, not declare `fileNames` as a list comprehension, that's just obfuscating things. Also you don't need the two explicit `close()` statements. And actually then you don't even need to explicity declare `memberArchive` or `parentZip` as variables. Shorter and clearer.

Comment: @smci, I added a snippet showing the use of with blocks and iterating through the file list as a more-mature example of how to do this.  I didn't rename the variables, though.  Let me know if that doesn't capture the intent of your suggestion correctly.

Comment: this version is much nicer, but keeping the camelCase variable names like `fileNames`, `parentZip` is just plain unPythonic, it makes the code look foreign and PERL/C++/C#/JS. So: `file_names`, `parent_zip`.  [Essentially no serious Python coders use camelCase, since long before 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function)

Comment: Good job with the package. I wish I could accept this as second answer. Hey, do your users worry if this is legally clean, and officially supported? [*"Most ZIP libraries have declined to implement Deflate64, citing its proprietary nature... The best hope seems to be the infback9 extension to zlib. This was developed in 2003 by Mark Adler, an original author of zlib, and is kept in the source repository of zlib, but it is not officially supported and contains no build tooling and is not distributed with zlib packages."*](https://pypi.org/project/zipfile-deflate64/) Needs to be shorter, clearer

Comment: Fantastic, it works. I used `pip install zipfile-deflate64`