# Reading a zipfile with pandas

Tags: pandas, windows, zip, deflate

I am currently trying to read a csv file that I compressed into a zip file (this zip file only contains my csv). I tried to simply write `pd.read_csv("trigramme_matrix.zip")` (as suggested in the documentation) but this returns `NotImplementedError: compression type 9 (deflate64)`.
I then tried to solve my problem using the zipfile module with `z = zipfile.ZipFile("trigramme_matrix.zip", "r")` and then `pd.read_csv(z.read("trigramme_matrix.csv"))` but it keeps throwing the same error.

I searched if I could get any insight on this error but the infos I got didn't help me much...

I thank you by advance.

Comment: Looks like your file has been compressed using 7-zip  - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflate#Deflate64/Enhanced_Deflate

Comment: @Mortz, I don't know, I just manually compressed it on my computer (Windows 10)... I don't see how I could get myself out of this issue... I am currently reading several topics on this but it does not help that much unfortunately

Comment: This old post seems to have relevant information [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809651/opening-zipfile-of-unsupported-compression-type-silently-returns-empty-filestrea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809651/opening-zipfile-of-unsupported-compression-type-silently-returns-empty-filestrea)

Comment: @EmmanuelDonald thanks for answering, I already stumbled across this post but I cannot wrap my head around... I've seen this which could be a start to a solution : A command-line Workaround is to unzip, then rezip, to get a plain type 8: Deflated.

But unfortunately I've got no idea how to unzip then rezip to get a type 8... what is the command line for this please ?(if you were to know it)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Windows like I am, please let me know if that is not the case. Unzipping a type 9 Zip file is easy in Windows XP and higher because they have inbuilt support for Zip files. I assume you are doing it before running the python code. If you want to do this at runtime, the old post which we came across has code to unzip at runtime using the software 7Zip.

Step 1: Extracting the csv from the type 9 Zip file

[image]

Windows Explorer will open the Zip file like any normal folder. Have to copy the csv file in the zip file and paste it inside desired folder.

Step 2: We can use Windows Explorer to zip the csv again, this time to a normal zip (Not type 9), which is the default used by Windows Explorer

[image]

Step 3: If you want to use the command line for some reason, one way is to get some unzip software which works with the command line, for example http://stahlworks.com/dev/unzip.exe

Please make sure you scan it using your antivirus

[image]