# Try-finally decorator to clean up python object

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, decorator, resource-cleanup

It seems object cleanup is a pretty common problem I've encountered during my programing days. To date I have consistently used the `with` statement as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object)

I had another thought today which seems more elegant to me (because it does not require a with statement by the end user). The idea would be to use a try-finally decorator for objects of a certain type (have a cleanup method).

Just wondering if there is anything wrong with this practice or if there is something even better. I don't like that many of my classes need to be initialized using a with statement, but I also want to ensure my objects are closed properly. Here's a short example.

```
def cleanme(func):
    def _decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            self._cleanup()

    return _decorator


class IObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_name = "some_file.txt"
        self._file_object = None
        self._cleaned = True

    @cleanme
    def run(self):
        self._connect()
        while True:
            # do some things over a long period
            pass

    def _connect(self):
        self._file_object = open(self.file_name)
        self._cleaned = False

    def _cleanup(self):
        if not self._cleaned:
            self._file_object.close()
            self._cleaned = True
```

Comment: The point of 'with' is to get away from this "cleanup everything later" idea and explicitly state which resources you use. You should split your object in two parts, one that is a resource (hold that file objects and knows how to clean up) and another part that uses it, the 'run' method should be "with my_resources: while True: do_stuff()".

Comment: That gets extremely messy when using many IO style objects (say I have 3 sockets open to recieve data, a video feed object and some communication pipes, etc.). Instead I can just have a connect method and a close method that handles each one.

Comment: I guess this handles that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024925/python-create-a-with-block-on-several-context-managers

Answer (score 3):

Let me shoot a couple of holes in this.

One thought, you're obliging your classes to have a `cleanup()`, which is declared not in a place different from `run()`. So you're imposing a user's responsibility to implement and maintain it cleanly.

Destructors other than `__exit__` are pretty uncommon in Python, so the resource acquisition code may drift from `cleanup()` code, imposing a leak.

Second, you're making `file_object` an instance variable, thus widening its scope from a single function, which is also somewhat bad.

Answer (score 2):

I think this approach is ok as long as your client will only use your `IOObject` to do whatever `run` does, and won't want to call `connect` directly and then do some other operations using the `file_object` that got opened.

Context managers make it easy for the client to know exactly where they're acquiring/cleaning up a resource, and also gives them the flexibility to essentially do whatever they want with it, knowing that as soon as they leave the `with` block it will be cleaned up. With this approach it's less clear; a client would need to look at the code (or perhaps the documentation) to know that the `run` method will clean up for them, but that if `connect` is used directly, `cleanup` will need to be called to properly clean up.

There's also the Zen of Python rule *"Excplicit is better than Implicit"*. The `with` statement explicitly shows the client where a resource is being acquired and release. You lose that with the decorator approach.