# Appends text file instead of overwritting it

Tags: python, file

The context is the following one, I have two text file that I need to edit.
I open the first text file read it line by line and edit it but sometimes when I encounter a specific line in the first text file I need to overwritte content of the the second file.

However, each time I re-open the second text file instead of overwritting its content the below code appends it to the file...

Thanks in advance.

```
def edit_custom_class(custom_class_path, my_message):
    with open(custom_class_path, "r+") as file: 
        file.seek(0)
        for line in file:
            if(some_condition):
                file.write(mu_message)

def process_file(file_path):
     with open(file_path, "r+") as file:    
        for line in file:
            if(some_condition):
                edit_custom_class(custom_class_path, my_message)
```

Comment: Do you want to append or overwrite?

Comment: Also that huge block of code is helping no one understand your problem.

Comment: I want to overwritte it each time I enter to the method  edit_custom_class(custom_class_path, my_tag, my_message)

Comment: This will help others help you solve your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried using the `file.tell()` command? This will help you investigate where the file pointer currently is when you try to write.

Comment: Wait, you are attempting to read _and_ write to the file at the same time?

Comment: Why don’t you read it once, decide what needs to be changed (if anything), and then completely over-write the file?

Comment: @MartinEvans thank you for the tip I did not know this method, the pointer tells me that at the end of each call of  edit_custom_class(custom_class_path, my_tag, my_message) the pointer still stay at the end even if I call file.seek(0) this is really weird!

Comment: @RishavKundu not at all I think I explained the context properly. I have two text file, I read the first text files each time I encounter a specific line in the first text file I edit the second one(I need to overwritte it completely).

Comment: @LastBersekr you are attempting to modify the file as you read it `for line in file:
            if(some_condition):
                file.write(edit_line)`

Comment: You could consider "rw" as the file mode. Note, writing to a file at a given offset does not insert, it overwrites. If you need to insert you might consider creating a new file and then deleting the current one when complete.

Comment: @RishavKundu, yes I read a line and if this line matches the condition I overwritte it. I already did it with fileinput.input(file_path, inplace = True) and it was working perfectly but for some reason I want to use w  with open(file_path, "r+") as file instead.

Comment: @MartinEvans the point is that I need to overwritte and not insert at a given offset. With this code it inserts the new line at the end of my file when it should be supposed just to overwritte the given line with the new content...

Comment: You can modify the original file using a tempfile of fileinput http://stackoverflow.com/a/30777077/2141635, if you reopen the file with `w` and your code errors you lose everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, simultaneously reading and modifying a file is a bad thing to do. Consider using something like this. First read the file, make modifications, and then overwrite the file completely.

```
def modify(path):
    out = []
    f = open(path)
    for line in f:
        if some_condition:
            out.append(edited_line) #make sure it has a \n at the end
        else:
            out.append(original_line)
    f.close()
    with open(path,'w') as f:
        for line in out:
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: I think that could solve my problem but I would like to know why you consider it as a bad solution to read and write simultaneously in a file. Also, why with for line in fileinput.input(file_path, inplace = True) I am able to read and modify the file simultaneously without any problem. Thanks

Comment: Hm, there is no reason for it as such. I like simple solutions to things.

Comment: But you may find this link interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453267/is-it-possible-to-modify-lines-in-a-file-in-place

Comment: Most of the answers recommend not doing it, hehe. And by the way, if you look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput they are doing the same thing as here.

Comment: i.e. using a “buffer” of some sort, when using `inplace= True`

Comment: You convinced me to go for this solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not a good approach either as if anything happens after opening with `w` then you lose all your data

Comment: @PadraicCunningham then what is the best approach? :) I’m a beginner sorry.

Comment: The second part of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776900/python-how-to-add-a-space-string-to-the-end-of-every-line-in-a-text-conf/30777077#30777077

Comment: @PadraicCunningham and why is that method guaranteed to work?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don’t know what that means but I will ask OP to look into your answer.

Comment: @LastBerserkr please look at the answer which PadraicCunningham has linked to.

Comment: @RishavKundu. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html that is what move is doing

Comment: Thanks for helping me to get the best solution. :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham anyway the solution of Rishav Kundu should be fine because you say I can loose everything after opening the with 'w' but you forget that the statement with open as handle all kind of errors so in a case of a lost of data that will raise an error, right?

Comment: @LastBerserkr, nope, once open gets called with `w` your file is overwritten so you lose all your data

Comment: @LastBerserkr what he means is that, if there is an error while writing to the file, then you will lose all the data you had in the original file

Comment: The best thing to do is first write to a temporary file, and then _rename_ the temporary file

Comment: Ok, I see, so nothing change from your code except that I write to an other temp file instead and at the end I rename the file, right?