# Python asyncio.semaphore in async-await function

Tags: python, semaphore, python-3.5, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I am trying to teach myself Python's async functionality. To do so I have built an async web scraper. I would like to limit the total number of connections I have open at once to be a good citizen on servers. I know that semaphore's are a good solution, and the asyncio library has a [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#semaphores) class built in. My issue is that Python complains when using `yield from` in an `async` function as you are combining `yield` and `await` syntax. Below is the exact syntax I am using...

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

sema = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(5)

async def get_page_text(url):
    with (yield from sema):
        try:
            resp = await aiohttp.request('GET', url)
            if resp.status == 200:
                ret_val = await resp.text()
        except:
            raise ValueError
        finally:
            await resp.release()
    return ret_val
```

Raising this Exception:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-9b9bdb963407>", line 14
    with (yield from sema):
         ^
SyntaxError: 'yield from' inside async function
```

Some possible solution I can think of...

1. Just use the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator
2. Use threading.Semaphore? This seems like it may cause other issues
3. Try this in the beta of Python 3.6 for [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-525-asynchronous-generators) reason.

I am very new to Python's async functionality so I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: python3.7  doesn't allow using `yield from` with keyword `async`. `yield`, `yield from` is to use with decorator `@asyncio.coroutine`

Comment: Does BoundedSemaphore(5) mean you only make 5 requests per second? Or how does work?

Answer (score 33):

You can use the `async with` statement to get an asynchronous context manager:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.5
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession


sema = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(5)

async def hello(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with sema, session.get(url) as response:
            response = await response.read()
            print(response)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(hello("http://httpbin.org/headers"))
```

Example taken from [here](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html). The page is also a good primer for `asyncio` and `aiohttp` in general.

Comment: I find the example very interesting, however something surprises me. 
It is this line:  

async with sema, session.get(url) as response:  

How come you are using sema, session... on the same context manager? What does that line do? Can you explain a little?

Comment: Nothing special going on there, I think this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024925/python-create-a-with-block-on-several-context-managers

Comment: How's using semaphore different from limiting the connection pool size - https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#limiting-connection-pool-size

Comment: Why `BoundedSemaphore` takes argument 5? can we sent different inputs?

Answer (score 7):

OK, so this is really silly but I just replaces `yield from` with `await` in the semaphore context manager and it is working perfectly.

```
sema = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(5)

async def get_page_text(url):
    with (await sema):
        try:
            resp = await aiohttp.request('GET', url)
            if resp.status == 200:
                ret_val = await resp.text()
        except:
            raise ValueError
        finally:
            await resp.release()
    return ret_val
```

Comment: Even better, you can use the `async with` statement: `async with sema: [...]`

Comment: Async is also interesting for me, I found your topic interesting and vote to leave it here. BTW, could you share you whole code for ex on github?

Comment: Yes, I will do that and post a link in the comments a little later.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Here is the code... https://github.com/brucepucci/asyncio_scraper. I am trying to get all of the links that start with "gid" in this file structure... http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2016/

Answer (score 0):

For the **semaphore** **only**:

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

# ... later
async with sem:
    # work with shared resource
```

which **is equivalent** to:

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

# ... later
await sem.acquire()
try:
    # work with shared resource
finally:
    sem.release()
```

ref:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore