# python asyncio context manager: combine 2 "contexts" in 1 variable

Tags: python

I am trying to reuse the code shown in the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836800/python-asyncio-semaphore-in-async-await-function) answer:

Especially the part that does:

```
async with sema, session.get(url) as response:
    response = await response.read()
```

But I don't understand it.. how can 2 "contexts" (sema and session.get(url)) be combined into 1 variable?

Can anyone give me a quick explanation of that syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value from `sema`'s `__aenter__` method is simply threw away and not assigned to any local variable.

Below is an equivalent for non-async code:

```
with ctx1, open(file) as fh:
    content = fh.read()
```