# python asyncio - add semaphore to example from documentation

Tags: python

I am trying to reuse the code shown in the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836800/python-asyncio-semaphore-in-async-await-function) answer:

Especially the semaphore part that does:

```
async with sema, session.get(url) as response:
    response = await response.read()
```

I am having trouble repurposing it to a code that does not involve aiohttp.

Could anyone show me how to use a semaphore on the below example: (for instance having a `sema = asyncio.Semaphore(2)` that allows only 2 simultaneous computation of the factorial)?

```
import asyncio

async def factorial(name, number):
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number+1):
        print("Task %s: Compute factorial(%s)..." % (name, i))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        f *= i
    print("Task %s: factorial(%s) = %s" % (name, number, f))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    factorial("A", 2),
    factorial("B", 3),
    factorial("C", 4),
))
loop.close()
```

I tried

```
import asyncio

sema = asyncio.Semaphore(2)

async def factorial(name, number):
    async with sema:
        f = 1
        for i in range(2, number+1):
            print("Task %s: Compute factorial(%s)..." % (name, i))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            f *= i
        print("Task %s: factorial(%s) = %s" % (name, number, f))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    factorial("A", 2),
    factorial("B", 3),
    factorial("C", 4),
))
loop.close()
```

I also tried the solution posted below as a comment. Both returns `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`

Comment: `with (await sema):` should ok?

Comment: @stovfl no it does not work. I tried  `async with sema:` and your suggestion - both return error `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`

Comment: Tried your Second Example, works as expected, only **two** simultaneous running `def factorial`. As `asyncio` changes with every Python Release tell which Python and OS Version you are using. I'm on Python 3.4.2 and Linux.