# Split multiple same-level context managers to multiple lines in Python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, contextmanager

I know that the `with` statement supports multiple context managers on the same level, like so:

```
with open('foo.txt') as foo, open('bar.txt') as bar:
    do_something()
```

But what if the list of context managers is getting too long for a single line? e.g.:

```
with open('foo.txt') as foo, open('bar.txt') as bar, open('bla.txt') as bla, open('yada.txt') as yada:
    do_something()
```

Currently, these are invalid syntax in Python 3.7:

```
with (
    open('foo.txt') as foo,
    open('bar.txt') as bar,
    open('bla.txt') as bla,
    open('yada.txt') as yada, # same thing without the last trailing comma
):
    do_something()
```

```
with 
    open('foo.txt') as foo,
    open('bar.txt') as bar,
    open('bla.txt') as bla,
    open('yada.txt') as yada, # same thing without the last trailing comma
:
    do_something()
```

I could do:

```
foo = open('foo.txt')
bar = open('bar.txt')
bla = open('bla.txt')
yada = open('yada.txt')

with foo, bar, bla, yada:
    do_something()
```

But even THAT could grow too long as I add more context managers.

I could also do:

```
with open('foo.txt') as foo:
    with open('bar.txt' as bar:
        with open('bla.txt' as bla:
            with open('yada.txt') as yada:
                do_something()
```

But it's ugly. It also lacks semantic hints for the human reader. There's a reason why we would want to put multiple context managers on the same level in the first place.

I know it's very uncommon for *many* context managers to belong to the same level, but it's definitely a possibility.

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024925/create-a-with-block-on-several-context-managers does this help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a "with" block on several context managers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024925/create-a-with-block-on-several-context-managers)

Comment: Using `ExitStack` seems like the cleanest solution, although it does mean extra setup lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line continuations are your friend here...

```
with \
    open('foo.txt') as foo, \
    open('bar.txt') as bar, \
    open('bla.txt') as bla, \
    open('yada.txt') as yada \
:
    do_something()
```

This is actually specifically mentioned in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer for now. It seems like a good compromise between the cleanest solution (using `ExitStack`) and convenience (no need for extra setup lines).