# returning a single instance of a regex object's contents

Tags: python

I am writing a matching function, and I am wondering whether or not I can return only the first occurrence of a match.  Here is my code (which matches all of the instances of the url for a given line, not only the first)... this is before I attempted to select a single match:

```
def file_match(line, url):
    allmatches = re.search(r'<a href="(?P<url>.*?)"', line)
    if allmatches and allmatches.groupdict()['url'] == url:
        return allmatches.groupdict()['url']
    else: 
        return None
```

Does anyone have experience with this particular problem?
I was advised to use the '.sub' method via a regex object, but I really can't tell what I would be using for the arguments to this method.  I've tried a number of things but they all yield errors.

Here is an example of one such (failed) attempts:

```
def file_match(line, url):
    allmatches = re.search(r'<a href="(?P<url>.*?)"', line)
    if allmatches and allmatches.groupdict()['url'] == url:
        return re.sub(r'<a href="(?P<url>.*?)"', allmatches, 1)
    else: 
        return None
```

Is the problem that I am using the .search() method?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
jml

Comment: It matches *all* instances of a pattern, and I would like for it to match only *one*-- i have updated my question to include an attempt.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Here is my code (which works):".  Are you saying it doesn't work?  What are you saying, exactly?

Comment: As you will note above, I have updated my question.  What is unclear at this point?  The first bit of code performs, but the result is many matches per line (if there are more than one).  The 2nd is an attempt to single out the first match, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: @jml: I think we're going to need a little more background info here. How does the calling code look because this code will only return 1 match.

Comment: @jml: As you will note, the words "which works" indicate that the code works.  You appear to be saying that it doesn't actually do what you want.  If it doesn't do what you want, then it doesn't really "work".  It just happens to run without obvious errors.  Please be very, very careful about using words like "works" when you're talking about something that doesn't do what you want it to do.  It appears that it doesn't "work".

Comment: gotcha.  sorry about that.  i have updated the q again to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yet another update.
sorry for the trouble, but i think that it ended up being my fault.  when i used line.replace() i wasn't using the correct search string, only the test for the re module, which is too general in terms of what i wanted to match.

Here is the answer that ended up fixing my problem:

```
 line.replace('<a href="' + test_str + '">', '<a href="' + re_string + '">')
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to do a little more reading on [Match Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects).

In particular [Groups](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using the following:  allmatches.group(1) ... but this doesn't work at all either.  It still yields multiple matches.

Comment: unfortunately I just can't even begin to replicate the behaviour you are talking about, sorry! :(