# tell() returns incorrect result when iterating through a file

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [file.tell() inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145082/file-tell-inconsistency)

Consider a file content

```
D:\temp>od -c test.txt
0000000   x   x   x   x   x  \r  \n   y   y   y   y   y  \r  \n   z   z
0000020   z   z   z  \r  \n   t   t   t   t   t
0000032
```

When I iterate through this file and subsequently `tell()` the current position, each time it returns an incorrect result (the result indicates, its at the end)

```
>>> with open("test.txt","r+") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print fin.tell(), line.strip()


26 xxxxx
26 yyyyy
26 zzzzz
26 ttttt
```

But when I read the file linearly, the result Concords with the expectation

```
>>> with open("test.txt","r+") as fin:
    while True:
        line = fin.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print fin.tell(), line.strip()


7 xxxxx
14 yyyyy
21 zzzzz
26 ttttt
```

It seems that when iterating through the file, it either buffers through the entire content or at least reads past end before starting the iteration.

Is it a known documented behavior

Comment: It is known documented behaviour, yes.

Comment: Uh-oh.  Are you saying that my answer to that [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340283/how-to-write-to-a-specific-line-in-file-in-python/14340352#14340352) is wrong :-(

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes its a duplicate, but somehow my search didn't figure that out, what you recollected from memory. I will add my close vote :-) instead of deleting for future reference (may be better search)

Comment: @mgilson: Yup, your answer to that question is indeed wrong. :-P

Comment: @Abhijit: Indeed, we keep (most) duplicates around for exactly that reason.

Comment: @mgilson: Sorry about that. I was equally confused but now enlightened by Martijn :-)

Comment: Closed in 8 mins :-( Thanks to @Martijn

Comment: @Abhijit -- Thanks for doing a read-behind on me to keep me honest.  I've removed that portion the answer now.