# Replacing and writing a file python

Tags: python-3.x, replace, file-writing

I want the following piece of code to replace few strings in a file and save the changes. It is doing the right job but just adding the changed lines to the previous file without replacing it. I just want the file to be overwritten. What's wrong in my code?

```
import os
import sys

fileToSearch  = 'sample.csv'

replace_values = {
    'text1'     :   'text1_new',
    'text2'     :   'text2_new',
    'text3'     :   'text3_new'
}
with open(fileToSearch, 'r+') as tempFile:
    for line in tempFile:
        for key, val  in replace_values.items():
            if key in line: 
                tempFile.write(line.replace(key, key.replace(key, val)))
```

Comment: This question seems to tackled [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778697/how-to-replace-update-text-in-a-file-line-by-line) already.

Comment: At the end can't you just rename the temporary file to the file name you are reading?

Comment: You're reading and writing to the file at the same time which is causing the inconsistency.