# How to iterate over files and replace text

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm python beginner: how can I iterate over csv files in one directory and replace strings e.g.

```
ww into vv
.. into --
```

So, I do not want to replace lines having ww into vv, just those string on this line. I tried something  like

```
#!/Python26/
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
for f in os.listdir(path):
    lines = f.readlines()
```

But how to proceed?

Comment: Yo want to replace some lines by other lines ? Is a replacing line of the same length as the replaced line ? If not, replacement causes a number of problems because we can't move bits apart to insert a chunk of bits at one position: the bits are physical elements.

Comment: Secondly, do you want to do replacements in one file or several? If you write for f in os.listdir(path) , f will be every file in the repertory path in turn. Do you want to make lines going from one file to another ? Where do the replacing lines come ? etc...etc... Your question must be more precise

Comment: I want to do these replacements on several files. Just those string conversions within a file.

Comment: Excuse me, I hadn't take enough attention to the first lines. In fact it is perfectly clear

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import os
import csv

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            cells = [ cell.replace('www', 'vvv').replace('..', '--')
                      for cell in row ]
            # now you have a list of cells within one row
            # with all strings modified.
```

Edit: Is it for you to learn/practice Python or you just need to get the job done? In the latter case, use the `sed` program:

```
sed -i 's/www/vvv/g' yourPath/*csv
sed -i 's/\.\./,,/g' yourPath/*csv
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow get an error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.csv'. Any idea what is causing this.

Comment: @atricapilla - sorry, I have edited it and now it should work with path+filename joining.

Comment: Thanks, this runs fine but does not seem to do this string replacement?

Comment: @atricapilla - well, you would have to write this data back. But see my comment about `sed`.

Comment: Why does SO not display this answer at the first position?

Answer (score 1):

As you want to make replacement of strings with strings of same length, the replacements can be done in place, that is to say rewriting only the bits that must be replaced , without having to record a new modified entire file.

So, with regex, this is very easy to do. The fact that the file is a CSV file has absolutely no importance in this method:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
import re
pat = re.compile('ww|\.\.')
dicrepl = {'ww':'vv' , '..':'--'}

for filename in listdir(path):
    with open(join(path,filename),'rb+') as f:
        ch = f.read()
        f.seek(0,0)
        pos = 0
        for match in pat.finditer(ch):
            f.seek(match.start()-pos, 1)
            f.write(dicrepl[match.group()])
            pos = match.end()
```

It's absolutely necessary to open in binary mode to do such treatments: it's the 'b' in the mode 'rb+'.

The fact that the file is opened in mode 'r+' allows to read AND write at any desired place in it (if it was opened in 'a' we could only write at the end of the file)

But if the files are so big that the **ch** object will be too much memory consuming, it should be modified.

If the replacements would be of different length than the original strings, it's quasi obligatory to record a new file with the modifications made. (if length of the replacing strings are always less than length of the replaced strings, it's a particular case, and it's still possible to process without having to record a new file. It may be interesting on a big file)

The interest of doing **f.seek(match.start()-pos, 1)** instead of **f.seek(match.start(), 0)** is that it moves the pointer from position **pos** to position **match.start()** without the pointer having to be moved from position **0** to **match.start()** then from **0** to **match.start()** each time.

On the contrary, with **f.seek(match.start(), 0)** the pointer must be first moved back to position **0** ( beginning of the file) then be moved forward while counting the *match.start()* number of characters to stop at the right position **match.start()** because the **seek(... , 0)** means that the position is attained from the beginning of the file, while **seek(... , 1)** means that the moving is made from the CURRENT position.
EDIT:

If you want to replace only the isolated 'ww' strings and not the 'ww' chunks in longer strings 'wwwwwww', the regex must be

```
pat = re.compile('(?<!w)ww(?!w)|(?<!\.)\.\.(?!\.)')
```

It's a possibility with regexes which can be obtained with **replace()** without tricky string manipulations.

EDIT:

I had forgotten the **f.seek(0,0)** instruction after **f.read()** . This instruction is necessary to move back the file's pointer to the beginning of the file, because during the reading the pointer is moved until the end.

I have corrected the code and now it works.

Here is a code to follow what's being processed:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
import re
pat = re.compile('(?<!w)ww(?!w)|(?<!\.)\.\.(?!\.)')
dicrepl = {'ww':'vv' , '..':'ZZ'}

path = ...................................

with open(path,'rb+') as f:
    print "file has just been opened, file's pointer is at position ",f.tell()
    print '- reading of the file : ch = f.read()'
    ch = f.read()
    print "file has just been read"+\
          "\nfile's pointer is now at position ",f.tell(),' , the end of the file'
    print "- file's pointer is moved back to the beginning of the file : f.seek(0,0)"
    f.seek(0,0)
    print "file's pointer is now again at position ",f.tell()
    pos = 0
    print '\n- process of replacrement is now launched :'
    for match in pat.finditer(ch):
        print
        print 'is at position ',f.tell()
        print 'group ',match.group(),' detected on span ',match.span()
        f.seek(match.start()-pos, 1)
        print 'pointer having been moved on position ',f.tell()
        f.write(dicrepl[match.group()])
        print 'detected group have been replaced with ',dicrepl[match.group()]
        print 'now at position ',f.tell()
        pos = match.end()
```

Comment: `dicrepl(...)` - this is probably not how you want to access a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

See the other answers for information on replacing strings. I want to add more information about iterating files, the first part of the question.

If you want to recurse through a directory and all subdirectories, use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk). `os.listdir()` does not recurse, or include the directory name in the filenames it generates. Use `os.path.join()` to form a more complete pathname.