# Append or remove some text in a file at a specific line in Python

Tags: python, file, unix, text

I want to edit an Apache2 config file within a python script. I want to add or remove a domain name to the ServerAlias directive so the script needs to edit a specific file and search for a line that starts with "ServerAlias" and append or remove a specific domain name to that line.

I'm not sure how to do it, any hint at documentation would be appreciated, I am also considering using a subprocess to use some bash tools like sed.

Comment: Why does it need to be Python?

Comment: Because it is part of a Django project so it would be nice to use the same language throughout the project. And because I like Python :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of tools you would need for your trade

1. [str.startswith](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)
2. [str.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) or just `+` (string concatination)
3. [readline](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) to read a file sequentially
4. [Offcourse opening and closing a file](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/lib/bltin-file-objects.html)
5. [write a file](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/lib/bltin-file-objects.html)

Comment: In case someone doesnt follow the link and see it, xreadlines is deprecated. Also he might need str.split or even regex if he is appending to values on the line

Comment: @jdi, Thanks I have updated the post. And as long as one can do without regex one should opt for it. As the OP just wants to check if the line begins with a certain string and just append a string onto it, OP may not need regex.

Comment: It looks like I have all I need to elaborate a script, thanks. If anybody could provide a simple example of how the tools interact together that would be just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

you can use fileinput.input with inplace mode:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("mifile", inplace=True):
    if line.startswith("ServerAlias"):
        line = doherewhatyouwant(line)
    print line,
```

from docs:

> if the keyword argument inplace=True is passed to fileinput.input() or
>   to the FileInput constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and
>   standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same
>   name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently).
>   This makes it possible to write a filter that rewrites its input file
>   in place. If the backup parameter is given (typically as
>   backup='.'), it specifies the extension for the backup
>   file, and the backup file remains around; by default, the extension is
>   '.bak' and it is deleted when the output file is closed. In-place
>   filtering is disabled when standard input is read.

Comment: add comma after line: `print line,` otherwise there are unnecessary  newlines.