# Python: How to add a line just before my matched pattern

Tags: python

I always do append my new lines just before the pattern `</IfModule>`.
How can i accomplish this with Python.

Just FYI, my file is not an XML/HTML to use lxml/element tree. `IfModule` is a part of my `.htaccess` file

My idea is to reverse the file and search for the pattern , if found append my line just after it. Not so sure how to proceed with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read through the file, and when you find the line you're supposed to output before output something first, then output the original line.

```
with open('.htaccess') as fin, open('.htaccess-new', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.strip() == '</IfModule>':
            fout.write('some stuff before the line\n')
        fout.write(line)
```

Updating the file inplace:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('.htaccess', inplace=True):
    if line.strip() == '</IfModule>':
        print 'some stuff before the line'
    print line,
```

Comment: Thats simply superb.. BTW rather using two files, can we achieve it with a single file. Is that possible?

Comment: @Sathy Yep. Updated to show how to update the file inplace (note the trailing `,` on `print line,` is important - it's not a typo ;)

Comment: Since I'm new to this Site, I'm still earning my reputation. Please bear me for not giving you +1 ;) You are Awesome..

Comment: @Sathy no worries - glad it helped. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @JonClements: Is it not fileinput.input('.htaccess', inplace=True)?

Comment: @Sathy Just for the record, ``fileinput.input`` with ``inplace=True`` still uses two files (it will create ``.htaccess.bak`` behind the scenes).

Comment: Thanks Iqc, i also learnt that from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: What to be done on this ?
        `Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "vanities.py", line 76, in <module>
        make_changes()
        File "vanities.py", line 66, in make_changes
        for each_line in fileinput(short_conf,inplace=True):
        TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

I tried with using **from fileinput import fileinput**, i got `ImportError: cannot import name fileinput`. Please help

Comment: @Sathy the code has already been corrected. rajpy was kind enough to point out a typo. The code now uses `for line in fileinput.input(...)` and just use `import fileinput` not `from fileinput import fileinput`

Answer (score 1):

Could try replacing `</IfModule>` with `\n</IfModule>`

```
with open('.htaccess', 'r') as input, open('.htaccess-modified', 'w') as output:
    content = input.read()
    output.write(content.replace("</IfModule>","\n</IfModule>"))
```