# Using Python to Remove All Lines Matching Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm attempting to remove all lines where my regex matches(regex is simply looking for any line that has yahoo in it).  Each match is on it's own line, so there's no need for the multiline option.

This is what I have so far...

```
import re
inputfile = open('C:\\temp\\Scripts\\remove.txt','w',encoding="utf8")

inputfile.write(re.sub("\[(.*?)yahoo(.*?)\n","",inputfile))

inputfile.close()
```

I'm receiving the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 170, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: you are not reading the file. You need something like `inputfile.readlines()`

Comment: You're trying to close 2 files you never opened, and naming a file opened for writing `inputfile` is confusing at best.

Comment: ... and [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is about replacing the matching content of a string. Not testing if a string [match](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match).

Comment: I'm trying to replace the matched content with nothing, hence "".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `fileinput` module if you want to modify the original file:

```
import re
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(r'C:\temp\Scripts\remove.txt', inplace = True):
   if not re.search(r'\byahoo\b', line):
      print(line, end="")
```

Comment: It's adding new lines between the text that still exists.  Any tips on how to avoid this?

Comment: I've tried print line, and print (line,) and print (line),  none seem to work.

Comment: @user2506096 use `print(line, end = "")` on py3.x

Comment: @JonClements thanks for your inputs, I was not able to reply due to poor internet connection and looks like you handled everything. :)

Comment: note: you can't use `inplace=1` and `fileinput.hook_encoded()` simultaneously so `fileinput`-based solution won't work if you need to decode the file content using encoding other than the default `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.

Comment: Note that the solution will also change the ownership of the target file. Just sth to keep in mind.

Comment: Using `re` on one line is the bad way. Use the python module `re` only for complicated algorithms (if we need to use regex match). To find a string in a single line, the built-in string method is much faster - `str.find()`, which returns a negative status (returns -1 if nothing was found or returns the index of the found expression in the string if that expression was found). So you would use the following syntax `if line.find('yahoo') < 0:` and your code will be a bit faster!

Answer (score 6):

Here's Python 3 variant of [@Ashwini Chaudhary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17221420/4279), to remove all lines that contain a regex `pattern` from a give `filename`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: remove-pattern <pattern> <file>"""
import fileinput
import re
import sys

def main():
    pattern, filename = sys.argv[1:] # get pattern, filename from command-line
    matched = re.compile(pattern).search
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=1, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            if not matched(line): # save lines that do not match
                print(line, end='') # this goes to filename due to inplace=1

main()
```

It assumes `locale.getpreferredencoding(False) == input_file_encoding` otherwise it might break on non-ascii characters.

To make it work regardless what current locale is or for input files that have a different encoding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
import sys
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

def main():
    encoding = 'utf-8'
    pattern, filename = sys.argv[1:]
    matched = re.compile(pattern).search
    with open(filename, encoding=encoding) as input_file:
        with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', encoding=encoding,
                                dir=os.path.dirname(filename),
                                delete=False) as outfile:
            for line in input_file:
                if not matched(line):
                    print(line, end='', file=outfile)
    os.replace(outfile.name, input_file.name)

main()
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to read the file try something like:

```
import re
inputfile = open('C:\\temp\\Scripts\\remove.txt','w',encoding="utf8")

inputfile.write(re.sub("\[(.*?)yahoo(.*?)\n","",inputfile.read()))

file.close()
outputfile.close()
```