# Replace a character by another in a file

Tags: python, file, file-io, python-3.x

I'd like to modify some characters of a file in-place, without having to copy the entire content of the file in another, or overwrite the existing one. However, it doesn't seem possible to just replace a character by another:

```
>>> f = open("foo", "a+")  # file does not exist
>>> f.write("a")
1
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> f.write("b")
1
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> f.read()
'ab'
```

Here I'd have expected "a" to be replaced by "b", so that the content of the file would be just "b", but this is not the case. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does the answer need to be pure python? Would you be open to using system commands?

Comment: @screenmutt: I'd prefer a Python way, but if there's no way to do this in Python, yes, I'm open to do this with system commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the mode you're using, in append mode, the file pointer is moved to the end of file before `write`, you should open your file in `w+` mode:

```
f = open("foo", "w+")  # file does not exist
f.write("samething")
f.seek(1)
f.write("o")
f.seek(0)
print f.read() # prints "something"
```

If you want to do that on an existing file without truncating it, you should open it in `r+` mode for reading and writing.

Comment: In fact, the file will not be empty, and I don't want to overwrite it.

Comment: Yeah, in fact you should be using r+ to open it read/write and not truncating

Answer (score 1):

Truncate the file using `file.truncate` first:

```
>>> f = open("foo", "a+") 
>>> f.write('a')
>>> f.truncate(0)  #truncates the file to 0 bytes
>>> f.write('b')
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> f.read()
'b'
```

Otherwise open the file in `w+`mode as suggested by @Guillaume.

Comment: This actually removes the content of the file.

Comment: only way to overwrite in append mode @doukremt

Answer (score 0):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('abc', inplace=True):
    line = line.replace('t', 'ed')
    print line,
```

This doesn't replace character by character, instead it scans through each line replacing required character and writes the modified line.

For example:
file 'abc' contains:

```
i want 
to replace
character
```

After executing, output would be:

```
i waned
edo replace
characeder
```

Will it help you? Hope so..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may be able to modify the example from this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/290494/1669208

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("test.txt", inplace=True):
    print line.replace(char1, char2),
```