# Python search and replace not working

Tags: python, string, replace

I have the following simple `HTML` file.

```
<html data-noop=="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
SUMMARY1
hello world
</body>
</html>
```

I want to read this into a `python` script and replace SUMMARY1 with the text "hi there" (say). I do the following in `python`

```
with open('test.html','r') as htmltemplatefile:
    htmltemplate = htmltemplatefile.read().replace('\n','')

htmltemplate.replace('SUMMARY1','hi there')
print htmltemplate
```

The above code reads in the file into the variable `htmltemplate`.
Next I call the `replace()` function of the string object to replace the pattern SUMMARY1 with "hi there". But the output does not seem to search and replace SUMMARY1 with "hi there". Here is what I'm getting.

```
<html data-noop=="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Hello World</title></head><body>SUMMARY1hello world</body></html>
```

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Because `open()` doesn't return a string object, it returns a file object. Also, you are only opening the file for reading (`'r'`). This is a also a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python

Comment: I think the mistake I was doing was in line 3. I changed it to <code>htmltemplate = htmltemplate.replace('SUMMARY1','hi there')</code> and it worked.

Comment: You also added `.read()` which wasn't there in your original post and changes a lot. But regardless, you still aren't actually editing the file, `'SUMMARY'` will still appear in `test.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open()` does not return a `str`, it returns a `file` object. Additionally, you are only opening it for reading (`'r'`), not for writing.

What you want to do is something like:

```
new_lines = []
with open('test.html', 'r') as f:
    new_lines = f.readlines()
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines([x.replace('a', 'b') for x in new_lines])
```

The `fileinput` library makes this a lot easier.