# Delete rows from csv file manually

Tags: excel, csv

Can you suggest a method to remove records from csv file, manually.
I have a csv file with many records, I need to delete unwanted records.
Is there any simplest method to remove the unwanted records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**manually:**

1. open the file in your desired text editor, i.e. notepad
2. delete the unwanted records (lines)
3. save the file

**semi automatically:**
get a good text editor, notepad++, pspad, ...
use the built in search and replace function, if you can provide an example string, or regular expression that can identify the unwanted records..

**automatically:**
describe how an unwanted record differs from a wanted record.
either by string comparision, regex, count of coloumns in row, or...
put that logic into a script, like python, and have that run through the file.
[SO question on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file in the notepad application and just delete the rows you don't want?