# add namespace/modify tag to XML with python

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I try to add namespace ( modify a tag ) to an XML doc using python
I come up with this simple solution

My input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assData version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.kama.com/it/eng/sgatInternal/assDataInternal/v1 /kama/it/eng/sgatInternal/assDataInternal/v1/assDataInternal-1_0.xsd" xmlns="http://xmlns.kama.com/it/eng/sgatInternal/assDataInternal/v1" xmlns:ext="http://xmlns.kama.com/it/eng/sgat/assData/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <su>suName</su>
        <PlayLocation>PlayLocation</PlayLocation>
        <fat>fatValue</fat>
        <Product kamaProductID="4xxx9-DOG325-Bare" suProductID="4x9 C325 BS" family="9x9" project="sgat" technology="ST1"/>
        <dog type="ENG" assdogID="assdogID" totalSNRCount="100"/>
        <Play step="PlayStep" type="Screen"/>
        <ProcessFlow>processFlow</ProcessFlow>
        <Recipe name="recipeName" type="PRD" version="1.00" id="recipeID"/>
        <PlayerSpecVersion>4.0</PlayerSpecVersion>
        <PlayDateTime start="2013-10-23T03:36:15+08:00" end="2013-10-23T03:36:15+08:00" timeZone="Europe/Rome"/>
        <ArrayType>1</ArrayType>
        <FirmWAR version="3.4"/>
    </Header>
    <assPlayReport>
        <RecSpec>
            <Bins>
                <Bin name="A" type="HB" number="1" pass="true"/>
                <Bin name="A-" type="HB" number="2" pass="true"/>
                <Bin name="B" type="HB" number="3" pass="false"/>
                <Bin name="C" type="HB" number="4" pass="false"/>
                <Bin name="F" type="HB" number="5" pass="false"/>
            </Bins>
            <Plays>
                <Play upperLimit="3.18" name="Play1" unit="mm" lowerLimit="3.27"/>
                <Play name="Play2"/>
                <Play upperLimit="22.42" name="Play2=3" unit="mm" lowerLimit="23.10"/>
            </Plays>
        </RecSpec>
        <Data>
            <SNRs>
                <SNR id="firstSNR" suSerialID="suSerialID" rework="0" startPlayDateTime="2013-10-23T03:36:15+08:00" endPlayDateTime="2013-10-23T03:36:15+08:00" fatdogID="fatdogID" fatPlateID="G" fatSubplateID="55" compositeSerialID="fatValue_fatdogIDG55_firstSNR" compositeSubplateID="fatValueG55" sourcedogID="fatdogID_S">
                    <Player DumpStop="DumpStop" targetActuatorID="targetActuatorID" operator="operator"/>
                    <Temperature unit="C">34.5</Temperature>
                    <Bread siteID="BreadSiteID" deviceID="BreadDeviceID" serialID="BreadSerialID" chipID="43" softWARVersion="2.1" arrayType="12" initializationFileVersion="1.0" hardWARID="BreadHardWARID" id="BreadID" firmWARVersion="3" isParallelExecution="false"/>
                    <Bins>
                        <FinalBin type="HB">4</FinalBin>
                        <Bin PlayName="FUNC" type="SB1">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="IMG" type="SB1">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="TUN" type="SB1">4</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="FUNC_FP" type="SB2">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="FUNC_PWR" type="SB2">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="IMG_LO" type="SB2">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="IMG_PROC" type="SB2">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="TUN_SENS" type="SB2">4</Bin>
                    </Bins>
                    <Plays>
                        <Play name="Play1">
                            <FReport>true</FReport>
                            <PReport>
                                <Result>3.19</Result>
                            </PReport>
                        </Play>
                        <Play name="Play2">
                            <FReport>false</FReport>
                            <PReport>
                                <Result>string result</Result>
                            </PReport>
                        </Play>
                    </Plays>
                </SNR>
                <SNR id="secondSNR" suSerialID="suSerialID" rework="0" startPlayDateTime="2013-10-23T03:37:15+08:00" endPlayDateTime="2013-10-23T03:38:15+08:00" fatdogID="fatdogID" fatPlateID="Q" fatSubplateID="12" compositeSerialID="fatValue_fatdogIDQ12_secondSNR" compositeSubplateID="fatValueQ12" sourcedogID="fatdogID_S">
                    <Player DumpStop="DumpStop" targetActuatorID="targetActuatorID" operator="operator"/>
                    <Temperature unit="F">34.5</Temperature>
                    <Bread siteID="BreadSiteID" deviceID="BreadDeviceID" serialID="BreadSerialID" chipID="43" softWARVersion="2.1" arrayType="12" initializationFileVersion="1.0" hardWARID="BreadHardWARID" id="BreadID" firmWARVersion="3" isParallelExecution="false"/>
                    <Bins>
                        <FinalBin type="HB">3</FinalBin>
                        <Bin PlayName="FUNC" type="SB1">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="IMG" type="SB1">3</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="FUNC_FP" type="SB2">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="FUNC_PWR" type="SB2">1</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="IMG_LO" type="SB2">3</Bin>
                        <Bin PlayName="IMG_PROC" type="SB2">3</Bin>
                    </Bins>
                    <Plays>
                        <Play name="Play1">
                            <FReport>true</FReport>
                            <PReport>
                                <Result>3.19</Result>
                            </PReport>
                        </Play>
                        <Play name="Play2">
                            <FReport>false</FReport>
                            <PReport>
                                <Result>string result</Result>
                            </PReport>
                        </Play>
                    </Plays>
                </SNR>
            </SNRs>
        </Data>
    </assPlayReport>
</assData>
```

My code inspired by [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close

def replace(file_path, pattern, subst):
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with open(abs_path,'w') as new_file:
        with open(file_path) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                new_file.write(line.replace(pattern, subst))
    close(fh)
    #Remove original file
    remove(file_path)
    #Move new file
    move(abs_path, file_path)


replace("c:\\temp\\stack_add_ext_input.xml","<Bins","<ext:Bins")  
replace("c:\\temp\\stack_add_ext_input.xml","/Bins>","/ext:Bins>") 
#wont work with this method
#replace("c:\\temp\\stack_add_ext_input.xml","<Bin","<ext:Bin") 
#replace("c:\\temp\\stack_add_ext_input.xml","/Bin>","/ext:Bin>") 
#wont work with this method
replace("c:\\temp\\stack_add_ext_input.xml","<Plays","<ext:Plays")  
replace("c:\\temp\\stack_add_ext_input.xml","/Plays>","/ext:Plays>")
```

However, this wont work as I have the Bins,Bin>,Plays,Play tag
Is there a easier way to do this?
I try to use the XML related package in python but I cant find a way to do it using the existing package.method easily...

I am thinking of implementing a state machine to keep track the state while reading the lines of the file.
But it seems to overkill....

Thx for the help

Comment: No one deserves to suffer like that.  Use an XML parser package.  And realize that namespace manipulation is not the same as namespace prefix manipulation; in fact, namespace prefixes are insignificant -- it's the namespace URIs that matter.  What is your actual end goal?

Comment: we have some files come in. Need to get transform using an XSD. The output will be just the added namespace prefix and some added attributes. Then the output will get loaded to a data analysis tool.

Comment: XSD's are for validation, not transformation; XSLT is for transformation.  Use XSLT or another XML library with a real XML parser; do not try to use string-level calls.  And, again, realize that namespace prefixes are irrelevant and cannot be controlled; namespace uri's matter and can be controlled.  Good luck.