# Finding and Replacing string in a line

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to open a file and search for a particular string in a line and replace it with another string.

I am trying the following code.

```
def myFunct(file, test, patter, replace):
    with open(file, mode='r') as f:
        for line in f.readline():
            if str(line).__contains__(test):
                if patter in line:
                    print("Found here\n")
                    print(line)
    f.close()
```

The code does not seem to go into the for loop.
Any suggestions ?

I have also tried a similar solution with the same problem.

[Find and Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python/39110#39110)

Comment: You mean `for line in f.readlines()`? Notice the `s`.

Comment: what is the difference between `test` and `patter`?

Comment: @ozgur test  is the name i search for and patter is the string i want to replace in the line containing test

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary f.readlines() also does not work i have tried it

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading the first line and iterate over the single characters of that line. You have to remove the `readline`:

```
def myFunct(file, test, patter, replace):
    with open(file, mode='r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if test in line and patter in line:
                print("Found here\n")
                print(line)
```

Comment: I have tried the update you mentioned but i am having the same problem. The code just does not seem to enter the for loop.