# Converting all integers in a file to zero

Tags: python, regex, string

Am new to python and I am trying to scan through a file and convert any integer I find to a value of 1.
Is there a regex I could use ? or some kind of function which I could use

Comment: `perl -pi -e 's/\d++/1/g' myfile.txt`. Why complicate matters?

Answer (score 1):

```
def numbers_with_zero(file_):
    import re
    # Note:current regex will convert floats and ints to 0
    # if one wants to just convert ints, and convert them to 1
    # do line = re.sub(r'[-+]?\d+',r'1',line)

    file_contents = []

    # read file, change lines
    with open(file_, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # this regex should take care of ints, floats, and sings, if any
            line = re.sub(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+',r'0',line)
            file_contents.append(line)

    # reopen file and write changed lines back
    with open(file_, 'w') as f:
        for line in file_contents:
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: be careful, he wants to convert each integer to 1, it means no doubles and r'1', not r'0' in re.sub function.

Comment: @Gregg heading says: Converting all integers in a file to zero. I ll'comment the function, so that users will have a choice.. thanks for you remark

Answer (score 0):

Olle Muronde, you can find information about how to rewrite lines in file in [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110/4694336). Each line of file could be considered as a string, the simplest way to replace some symbols by others is `re.sub` function from [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). I strongly recommend you to learn python documentation and to use google or stackoverflow search more often, because plenty good answers have been posted already.