# Modifying and writing data in an existing excel file using Python

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I have an Excel file(xlsx) that already has lots of data in it. Now I am trying to use Python to write new data into this Excel file. I looked at xlwt, xldd, xlutils, and openpyxl, all of these modules requires you to load the data of my excel sheet, then apply changes and save to a new Excel file. Is there any way to just change the data in the existing excel sheet rather than load workbook or saving to new files?

Comment: Is is a simple sheet that could be represented as a .csv file? if so, you can open as a text file in append mode and just begin writing lines to the bottom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: But I don't know if it will work with the excel file being binary.

Comment: @Aaron it's an Excel Sheet not .csv file. And I don't think it works the same way as a text file.

Comment: @JerryShi I understand it is currently an excel sheet, but can the data be represented as columns of  values? if so, you can export the existing sheet as a csv file, then use native python to write to the end of the file (append mode)

Comment: @Aaron You cannot always use CSV to replace something like XLSX. For one thing CSV files have no type information.

Comment: @CharlieClark that's why I asked if his data would support that... I realize it's not always possible, but that was the only other way to solve his problem given his constraints. (maybe not the **only** way, but the only one obvious to me)

Comment: @Aaron when the question specifies the file format then that is the place to start.

Comment: @JerryShi consider using built-in excel [Visual Basic](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Excel_VBA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible because XLSX files are zip archives and cannot be modified in place. In theory it might be possible to edit only a part of the archive that makes up an OOXML package but, in practice this is almost impossible because relevant data may be spread across different files.

Answer (score -1):

Please check Openpyxl once again. You can load the data, do things with python, write your results in a new sheet in the same file or same sheet and save it (as everything is happening in memory).

e.g:
load data

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx", data_only=True)
```

manipulate with python

```
# python codes
```

create sheet

```
some_sheet = wb.create_sheet("someSheet") # by default at the end
```

program to write in sheet

```
# program to write in sheet
```

save file (don't forget to close the  excel file if its open before saving, as it will raise "Permission Error")

```
wb.save("file.xlsx"
```

here is the link
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html