# how to join incorporate splitted lines with replacing data from a file into the same string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So as most of us are thinking it's a duplicate which is not, so what I'm trying to achieve is let's say there is a Master string like the below and couple of files mentioned in it then we need to open the files and check if there are any other files included in it, if so we need to copy that into the line where we fetched that particular text.

Master String:

> Welcome
>   How are you
>   file.txt
>   everything alright
>   signature.txt
>   Thanks

file.txt

ABCD
EFGH
tele.txt

tele.txt

> IJKL

signature.txt

> SAK

Output:

Welcome
How are you
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
everything alright  
SAK 
Thanks

```
for msplitin [stext.split('\n')]:
            for num, items in enumerate(stext,1):
                if items.strip().startswith("here is") and items.strip().endswith(".txt"):
                       gmsf = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd()+"\txt", items[8:]), "r")
                        gmsfstr = gmsf.read()
                        newline = items.replace(items, gmsfstr)
```

How to join these replace items in the same string format.

Also, any idea on how to re-iterate the same function until there are no ".txt". So, once the join is done there might be other ".txt" inside a ".txt.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Please do not change your question constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive approach that works with any level of file name nesting:

```
from os import linesep

def get_text_from_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        text = f.read()
        return SAK_replace(text)

def SAK_replace(s):
    lines = s.splitlines()
    for index, l in enumerate(lines):
        if l.endswith('.txt'):
            lines[index] = get_text_from_file(l)
    return linesep.join(lines)
```

Comment: @SAK my pleasure :) I think you checkmarked the wrong answer tho :)

Comment: i found out another problem, so when there is 2 level files i.e. file - file - file then there is an error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects"

Comment: one sec lemme try it

Comment: fixed some line separator issues, tested it up to file-file-file-file so should be good for any level. try it now and lemme know

Comment: @criagBurgler no luck yet, here is the error code - m.txt

D:/k/m.txt

[Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: u'D:/k/m.txt\r\n'
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Installation\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gevent\greenlet.py", line 522, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:\k\t.py", line 72, in start
    result = self.do_as(s)
  File "D:\k\core\tasks.py", line 159, in do_work
    replaced = '\n'.join(lines)
TypeError: sequence item 31: expected string or Unicode, NoneType found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121660/discussion-between-craig-burgler-and-sak).

Comment: @craigBurgler- I fixed the issue thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I changed the code so that line separators are handle by Python

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
s = """Welcome
How are you
here is file.txt
everything alright
here is signature.txt
Thanks"""

data = s.split("\n")
match = ['.txt']
all_matches = [s for s in data if any(xs in s for xs in match)]

for index, item in enumerate(data):
    if item in all_matches:
        data[index] ="XYZ"

data = "\n".join(data)
print data
```

Output:

```
Welcome
How are you
XYZ
everything alright
XYZ
Thanks
```

**Added new requirement:**

```
def file_obj(filename):
        fo = open(filename,"r")
        s = fo.readlines()
        data = s.split("\n")
        match = ['.txt']
        all_matches = [s for s in data if any(xs in s for xs in match)]
        for index, item in enumerate(data):
                if item in all_matches:
                        file_obj(item)
                        data[index] ="XYZ"

        data = "\n".join(data)
        print data
file_obj("first_filename")
```

Comment: added.. I replaced both .txt file by XYZ.. You can replace as your wish.. I did this because it will handle last amount of data.. no need to replace each & every string..

Comment: I think, the requirement is to open file - search string - if matched then replace. The demo code SAK has posted contains the operations like check if file exist, read file contents etc

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Thanks Harsha for your help.

Comment: @DineshPundkar - And I changed the code where it refers to open for reading files. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: @HarshaBiyani also, any idea on how to re-iterate the same function until there are no ".txt". So, once the join is done there might be other ".txt" inside a ".txt.hope i'm not confusing.

Comment: so it means, inside "here is file.txt" file, there might be again .txt ??

Comment: @HarshaBiyani yes Harsha

Comment: @HarshaBiyani thanks for the idea, i think what i was telling is more like an iteration, there could be a bunch of txt's and in that again a bunch. I know  I might be just creating a mess around here. But just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

We can create temporary file object and keep the replaced line in that temporary file object and once everything line is processed then we can replace with the new content to original file. This temporary file will be deleted automatically once its come out from the 'with' statement.

```
import tempfile
import re

file_pattern = re.compile(ur'(((\w+)\.txt))')
original_content_file_name = 'sample.txt'
"""
sample.txt should have this content.

Welcome
How are you
here is file.txt
everything alright
here is signature.txt
Thanks
"""
replaced_file_str = None


def replace_file_content():
    """
    replace the file content using temporary file object.
    """

    def read_content(file_name):
        # matched file name is read and returned back for replacing.
        content = ""
        with open(file_name) as fileObj:
            content = fileObj.read()
        return content

    # read the file and keep the replaced text in temporary file object(tempfile object will be deleted automatically).
    with open(original_content_file_name, 'r') as file_obj, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
        for line in file_obj.readlines():
            if line.strip().startswith("here is") and line.strip().endswith(".txt"):
                file_path = re.search(file_pattern, line).group()

                line = read_content(file_path) + '\n'
            tmp_file.write(line)
        tmp_file.seek(0)
        # assign the replaced value to this variable
        replaced_file_str = tmp_file.read()

    # replace with new content to the original file
    with open(original_content_file_name, 'w+') as file_obj:
        file_obj.write(replaced_file_str)

replace_file_content()
```