# How to update line of file in python

Tags: python

How to update existing line of file in Python?

Example: I want to update `session.xml` to `sesion-config.xml` without writing new line.

Input `A.txt`:

```
fix-config = session.xml
```

Expected output `A.txt`:

```
fix-config = session-config.xml
```

Comment: Do you want to override a single line, or override the whole file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution @TigerhawkT3 suggested would work great for small/medium files.
For extremely large files loading the entire file into memory might not be possible, and then you would want to process each line separately.
Something along these lines should work:

```
import shutil

with open('A.txt') as input_file:
    with open('temp.txt', 'w') as temp_file:
        for l in input_file:
            if l.startswith('fix-config'):
                temp_file.write('fix-config = session-config.xml\n')
            else:
                temp_file.write(l)

shutil.move('temp.txt', 'A.txt')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't mutate lines in a text file - you have to write an entirely new line, which, if not at the end of a file, requires rewriting all the rest.

The simplest way to do this is to store the file in a list, process it, and create a new file:

```
with open('A.txt') as f:
    l = list(f)

with open('A.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in l:
        if line.startswith('fix-config'):
            output.write('fix-config = session-config.xml\n')
        else:
            output.write(line)
```

Comment: there is an exact duplicate of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python). What do you think?

Comment: If you see a common question with a popular canonical duplicate, you can vote or flag the question for closure with that duplicate.

Comment: @Jarvis - Those are really familiar words. :P