# iteratively replace string in file and use the file in further commands in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, replace

The following code is supposed to replace a line in a file called "some_file" then use the new version of "some_file" in a python command and then repeat the process. When I run it the line in the file gets iteratively replaced based on the value of i with the new values but the further command doesn't use the new version of the file but the old one. Could someone give me a way around this problem?

```
 for i in range(0,N):
    with fileinput.input("some_file", inplace=True) as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line.replace("something", "something_else", 1), end='')
    python command using "some_file"
```

Comment: You aren't modifying the file, you are modifying a string retrieved from the file.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python

Comment: @Natecat I have the file open in an editor and I can see the line changing in it :/

Comment: @Natecat a python module as explained in the python documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/fileinput.html