# How to add the line number at the beginning of each line in a file

Tags: string, python-3.x, file

So.. I need to read a file and add the line number at the beginning of each line. Just as the title. How do you do it?

For example, if the content of the file was:

```
This
is
a
simple
test
file
```

These 6 lines, I should turn it into

```
1. This
2. is
3. a
4. simple
5. test
6. file
```

Keep the original content, but just adding the line number at the beginning.

My code looks like this so far:

```
def add_numbers(filename):
    f = open(filename, "w+")
    line_number = 1
    for line in f.readlines():
        number_added = str(line_number) + '. ' + f.readline(line)
        line_number += 1
        return number_added
```

But it doesn't really show anything as the result. I have no clues how to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems I see in your code:

- You indentation is not correct. Everything below the `def add_numbers():` should be indented one level.
- It is good practice to close a file handle at the end of your method.

A similar question to yours was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python). Looking at the various solutions posted there, using `fileinput` seems like your best bet because it allows you to edit your file in-place.

```
import fileinput
def add_numbers(filename):
    line_number = 1
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
        print("{}. {}".format(line_number, line))
        line_number += 1
```

Also note that I use `format` to combine two strings instead adding them together, because this handles different variable types more easily. A good explanation of the use of format can be found [here](https://pyformat.info/).