# Editing text in a file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file (file1.txt) containing pattern like this.

```
****
****
****
****
```

I want to replace it by `**`. I can use command  something like this `sed -i 's/\*{4}/**/' file1.txt` in linux to get in place replacement. But I want to do this operation in Windows environment using python script.

```
import re
with open ('file1.txt') as fil1:
     for line in fil1:
         re.sub('^\*{3}[*]*','**',line)
```

But this script does not seem to replace `****` by `**` in place in the file. How can I get in place file replacement (similar to `sed` command) in python?

Edit:

I do not want to read file line by line, replace text and write the line into another file. I want to do something like `sed -i` to do in place file replacement in python using regular expressions.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: The problem is that you're not writing anything. You are just reading from the file to the variable line and change the variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: You _cannot_ get any kind of 'in-place' changes in a file. You only can read from it and write into it. And all of this has to be done explicitly.

Comment: Doesn't `re.sub` replace and write in the file like `sed` ?

Comment: @dfs3w, no, it doesn't. Also, given that you ignore its return value, in your code it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: OK. How can I do in place replacement in python using regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to edit the file inlace, but you open the file in read mode, so it is not open for writing.

Furthermore, you are calling re.sub which returns a new string that you do not capture and attempt to write.

Editing a file inplace is challenging with the builtin functions, but is made easy with the `fileinput` module:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput('file1.txt', inplace=True) as fil1:
    for line in fil1:
        text = re.sub('^\*{3}[*]*','**', line.rstrip()).strip()
        if text:
            print(text) # inside the `with` clause, print writes to the file automatically
```

Comment: It inserts blank like in the last line of the file. Do you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: @dfs3w Your input file probably has that. Check my edit? And if it helps, do mark it accepted :)