# File parsing with python

Tags: python, batch-file

How to replace a specific line or a string with another string on a text file with Python? I tried this method:

```
with open("textfile.txt","r") as f:
    newline = []
    for word in f.readlines():        
        newline.append(word.replace("previous_line","new_line"))
```

Comment: I think you should refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python

Comment: how to index the function to replace the next line for exaple we have line1 and line2 i want to replace the second line refering to line1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
   data=f.read()
```

Now we have all the contents of a file in variable `data` , now assuming each line is ending with a `\n` . We can split it .

```
mylines = data.splitlines()
for x in range(1,len(mylines)-1):
    if myline[x]=='thanks for help':
       myline[x] = myline[x-1]
data = "\\n".join(mylines)
f.write(data)
```

of course, if the line replacing the thanks for help is not the previous line, u may need to create some logic there.

Comment: how to replace tho whole line without indicating strings into it , it means to replace (ANY) into this line

Comment: Can u please explain more. What will be the reference where replace need to happen

Comment: for example i have line1:helloo world ; line2: thanks for help ; i want to remove line2 and replace it with other string refering to line1 it means i shold index my function with hello world for example

Comment: sir how could i modify a variable with python for example i have a=test.c => a=test.h

Comment: please explain more and if above explanation answer your question mark it as an answer.

Comment: i want to modify the extention of a file into a text file automatically from test.c to test.o

Comment: if that is a file only   `os.rename(srcfile,destinationfile)` but if u want to replace inside text u can simply use `data.replace(".c",".h")` or can use regex also.

Comment: how could i run a python script from a batch file ?

Comment: please post a separte script for that . it is same as you execute other commands from batch file. `python scrpit.pl`

Comment: how to index the path in while loop 
'while i<3: 
     "\test\\ss\\tsss(i).inc"
     i +=1'

Comment: please open a separate question, and also please explain more. not clear enough.