# reading XML with different encoding using python mindom

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, minidom

I wrote a script reading XML files using minidom:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
for File in Data['FileList']:
    Xml = parse(File)
#do something
```

which runs fine, but some guys are creating XMLs defining UTF-8 encoding in the XML and using German Umlaute in tags so I ran into xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token).

If I change manually in the XML to encoding="ISO-8859-1" it runs fine.

Is there a more elegant way of changing the encoding, instead of editing the XML files, e.g. telling minidom to use a different encoding than defined in the XML?

Comment: It is a serious error to create XML files with an XML declaration saying `encoding="UTF-8"` when the actual encoding is ISO-8859-1. I think you should tell the "guys" to stop creating these bad XML files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you this solution:

Before parsing the file, open it normally and replace the first line of it which corresponds to the XML header with this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

You then save the file and passe it to `minidom.parse()` function.

This may help you to replace the first line line in each file: [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: This is I want to avoid, but it seems the only robust way to read it in. So there seems to be no way of having an option in minidom to define a different Encoding while parsing the file.

Comment: I did not mean manually opening the file, but programmatically (something like this:  `with open(File, 'rw') as my_file: #replace and save, then passe the file to parse()`)