# Open a JS file and edit a line with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to modify a specific line in a js file using python.

Here's the js file :

```
...
hide: [""]
...
```

Here's my python code :

```
with open('./config.js','r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

with open('./config.js','w') as f:
   for line in lines:
       line = line.replace('hide', 'something')
       f.write(line)
```

So it works but this is not what I want to do.

I want to write 'something' between the brackets and not replace 'hide'.

So I don't know how to do it: Do I have to replace the whole line or can I just add a word between the brackets?

Thanks

Comment: Would you try `line = line.replace('hide', 'hide: [\"something\"]')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace text at this exact line  you could just do:

```
with open('./config.js','r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

with open('./config.js','w') as f:
   new_value = 'Something New'
   for line in lines:
       if line.startswith('hide'):
           line = 'hide: ["{}"]'.format(new_value)
       f.write(line)
```

---

or alternatively in the conditional

```
           if line.startswith('hide'):
               line = line.replace('""', '"Something new"')
```

---

Here's way to replace any value in brackets for `hide` that starts with any spacing.

```
lines = '''\
first line
            hide: [""]
       hide: ["something"]
last line\
'''
new_value = 'new value'

for line in lines.splitlines():
    if line.strip().startswith('hide'):
       line = line[:line.index('[')+2] + new_value + line[line.index(']')-1:]
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
first line
            hide: ["new value"]
       hide: ["new value"]
last line
```

Comment: what if `hide: [""]` not alone in line?

Comment: I think that's what author meant and why I said it will replace only this exact line

Comment: hide is alone in line

Comment: There is a way to change whatever there is between the brackets ? For exapme if I have "something" and the next time "somethingelse" without modifying my python code

Comment: Updated my answer based on @SpghttCd idea.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Comment: Ah ! And last question : I have like 15 spaces before 'hide' so when i put it in my code this is ugly. There is a way that python takes them into consideration without copy/paste 15 spaces ? if it's too complicated don't worry I'll go with that which is already super fine

Comment: Updated my answer, you can try it.

Comment: Perfect, you're the boss :p

Comment: Just for the sake of ease and readability: for this issue imo the `replace`-approach would fit better than searching for bracket's indices. But anyway, now you should have anything you need, so you can pick what you like... :)

Comment: `replace` shown in your example will work only if value of hide is `[""]`, using brackets searching replace whatever's between them.

Answer (score 1):

If `hide: [""]` is not ambiguous, you could simply load the whole file, replace and write it back:

```
newline = 'Something new'

with open('./config.js','r') as f:
   txt = f.read()

txt = txt.replace('hide: [""]', 'hide: ["' + newline + '"]')

with open('./config.js','w') as f:
   f.write(txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fileinput` and replace it inplace:

```
import fileinput
import sys

def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

replaceAll("config.js",'hide: [""]','hide: ["something"]')
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315088/3959965)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `re.sub()`

```
import re
with open('./config.js','r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

with open('./config.js','w') as f:
   for line in lines:
       line = re.sub(r'(\[")("\])', r'\1' + 'something' + r'\2', line)
       f.write(line)
```

It works by searching for a regular expression, but forms a group out of what you want on the left (`(\[")`) and the right (`("\])`).  You then concatenate these either side of the text you want to insert (in this example `'something'`).

The bounding `( )` makes a group which can be accessed in the replace with `r'\1'`, then second group is `r'\2'`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have "hide" anywhere else in the file, then you could just do

```
with open('/config.js','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('./config.js','w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.replace('hide [""]', 'hide ["something"]')
        f.write(line)
```