# How to save the file using fileinput in python? Giving AttributeError: 'FileInput' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file-io

I am saving the file using fileinput module but throwing  AttributeError: 'FileInput' object has no attribute 'read'

i have closed the file by looking into some stack overflow questions

```
 import re
 import fileinput
 rx = r'\d+(?=:$)'
 with fileinput.input('branch.txt', inplace=True) as fh:
    data = fh.read()
    print(re.sub(rx , lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), data, 1, re.M))
    data.close()
    fh.close
```

if I am using normal mode i am getting io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

```
 import re
 rx = r'\d+(?=:$)'
 with open('branch.txt','a') as fh:
    fh_n = fh.read()
    x = (re.sub(rx, lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), fh_n, 1, re.M))
    #print (x)
    fh.write(x)
    fh.close()
```

Comment: Why do you want `fileinput` instead of builtin `open`?

Comment: import re
rx = r'\d+(?=:$)'
with open('branch.txt','a') as fh:
    fh_n = fh.read()
    x = (re.sub(rx, lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), fh_n, 1, re.M))
    print (x)
    fh.write(x)
    fh.close()
got error io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: So, all you want is to read and write to the same file? See [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Yes, i m trying to do that. Is there any issue in code. because read mode perfectly working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I am using normal mode i am getting io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
>
> ```
>  import re
>  …
>  with open('branch.txt','a') as fh:
> ```

That's because one cannot read from a file opened with mode `'a'` (append).