# How to add a text after certain text found in a file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a switch case.If option 1 is pressed then some info is added to a csv file and after exit the case if again run the code and choose option 2 then it search some text in file and if found then add something to it.

I have tried the code given below.It runs option 1 correct but give errors in option 2.

```
from datetime import datetime
import fileinput

today = datetime.now()
In = str(today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y , %H:%M:%S"))
In1=In.rpartition(' , ')[0]
today = datetime.now()
Out = str(today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y , %H:%M:%S"))
out1=Out.rpartition(' , ')[2]
name=input("enter name of employee: ")
attend1=name+" , "+In1
f = open("Attend.csv", "a")
filename="Attend.csv"
while True:
    print("1. Enter In Time\n2. Enter Out Time")
    choice=input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice == "1":
        attend = name+" , "+In
        print(attend)
        f.write(attend+"\n")
    elif choice == "2":
        attend = name+" , "+Out
        print(attend)
        f = open("Attend.csv", "r+")
        for lines in f:
            if attend1 in lines:
                lines=lines.replace(lines,lines+" , "+out1)
            f.write(lines+"\n")
     else:
        print("Please choose the correct entry.")
        break
f.close()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here, could you give us more details? I guess you are trying to keep record of when employees start and end their journey. Why are you taking the time just at the begining?

Answer (score 0):

The first case is easy, since it is just adding a line to the end of file. The second case is not working because you are just adding the time at the end, without  [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the line and not searching for your line to be modified.

There is a problem in case the `out` time was added in the same iteration as the `in`, that means the file modification is not visible until you close the file, so you wouldn't find the `in` register.

By using this answer on [how to search and replace a line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110/11335072) I came up with this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from os import fdopen, remove
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move

def end_employee_day(filename, employee, end_time):
    updated = False
    #Create temp file
    temp, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with fdopen(temp,'w') as new_file:
        with open(filename) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                # Search for employee in register
                if line.startswith(employee) and len(line.split(" , ")) == 3:
                    if updated:
                        print(f"Multiple in register found for {employee}")
                    updated = True
                    line = f"{line.strip()} , {end_time}\n"
                    print(line)
                new_file.write(line)
    #Remove original file
    remove(filename)
    #Move new file
    move(abs_path, filename)
    if not updated:
        print(f"In register not found for {employee}")

filename = "Attend.csv"
today = datetime.now
while True:
    print("1. Enter In Time\n2. Enter Out Time")
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice not in ("1", "2"):
        print("Quitting")
        break
    name = input("enter name of employee: ")
    if choice == "1":
        with open(filename, "a") as f:
          now_time = str(today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y , %H:%M:%S"))
          attend = f"{name} , {now_time}\n"
          print(attend)
          f.write(attend)
    elif choice == "2":
        now_time = str(today().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        end_employee_day(filename, name, now_time)
```

This allows to add registers of multiple employees in the same run. I did this since it seemed a little weird for me to add the `in` and `out` times for the same employee at the same time.

This code does not keep you from entering multiple `in` registers of the same employee without having registered the `out` time. The `out` time will be added to all `in` registers it finds.

Hope it helps, do not hesiste if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks for your help.I am unable to understand one line. i.e.                                        line = f"{line.strip()} , {end_time}\n"

Comment: You could check out the docs about [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) or f-strings, which are introduced in Python 3. Short story, f-string allows you to replace expressions evaluated at runtime on strings.