# Replacing a line in file moves another line to a superior one

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file

I have a py file like the following one:

```
final_data = ','.join(ordered_data.iloc[0].astype(str).values.tolist())
runtime = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='xgboost-whatever', #Endpoint mark                                           
                                       ContentType='text/csv',
                                       Body=final_data)
```

What I want is to replace the line with the EndpointName for another line. Taking in account the SO question [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python) I have coded this:

```
def replace(file_path, subst):
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with fdopen(fh,'w') as new_file:
        with open(file_path) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                if re.search('response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(.*?)#Endpoint mark',line):
                    new_file.write(line.replace(line, subst))
                else:
                    new_file.write(line)
    #Remove original file
    remove(file_path)
    #Move new file
    move(abs_path, file_path)


file_path = '/home/whatever'
subst = "        response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='xgboost-otro', #Endpoint mark "

replace(file_path, subst)
```

However, running the previous code gets me something different that what I was looking for:

```
final_data = ','.join(ordered_data.iloc[0].astype(str).values.tolist())
runtime = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='xgboost-otro', #Endpoint mark                                                                              ContentType='text/csv',
                                       Body=final_data)
```

So I lose the ContentType line, which is converted to a comment. 
If I introduce an `\n` character at the end of `subst` it deletes the ContentType line. How could I solve it?

Comment: `line.replace(line, subst)` is so cryptic way of saying `subst`. But you need to add a newline. Use `new_file.write("{}\n".format(subst))` instead of `new_file.write(line.replace(line, subst))`

Comment: Adding the 'r' has solved the problem. Thanks! Make an answer so that I can accept it (if you want, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in read mode:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as old_file:
```

Also, `line.replace(line, subst)` is so cryptic way of saying `subst`. You need to add a newline at the end of `subst` anyway or use

```
new_file.write("{}\n".format(subst))
```

instead of

```
new_file.write(line.replace(line, subst))
```

Comment: @CharifDZ It makes a difference though. I can't find the comment on SO that explained it, I will share once I find it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `\n` at the end of the line:

```
subst = "        response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='xgboost-otro', #Endpoint mark\n"
```

and in your replacing logic:

```
   new_file.write(subst)
```

Comment: It might not be enough since OP syas the ContentType line is removed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. As I mentioned in my question, if I make this, the whole ContentType line gets deleted

Comment: It didn't remove it, when I tried it? what do you mean by remove it? you mean the line will not appear at all?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I mean

Comment: but it didn't remove it in my case, and there is no way that it will be remove it? are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It seems very weird to me as well. I guess it is somehow related to not opening the file in read mode, I don't know

Comment: the mode is by default a in reading mode so this is not the problem? the error was in using the replace that you didn't need it at all, just write the subst direcly