# Replace a specific line in a file without looping

Tags: python

I have a huge file with a problematic character at line 9073245. So I want to replace/remove that character at that specific line while keeping the rest of the file intact. I found the following solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110/12785645):

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move, copymode
from os import fdopen, remove

def replace(file_path, pattern, subst):
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with fdopen(fh,'w') as new_file:
        with open(file_path) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                new_file.write(line.replace(pattern, subst))
    #Copy the file permissions from the old file to the new file
    copymode(file_path, abs_path)
    #Remove original file
    remove(file_path)
    #Move new file
    move(abs_path, file_path)
```

But instead of reading line by line, I just want to replace line number 9073245 and be done with it. I thought `getline` from `linecache` might work:

```
import linecache

def lineInFileReplacer(file_path, line_nr, pattern, subst):
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with fdopen(fh,'w') as new_file:
        bad_line = linecache.getline(file_path, line_nr)
        new_file.write(bad_line.replace(pattern, subst))
    #Copy the file permissions from the old file to the new file
    copymode(file_path, abs_path)
    #Remove original file
    remove(file_path)
    #Move new file
    move(abs_path, file_path)
```

but `new_file.write()` does not seem to include the replacement for `bad_line`.

How can I replace a line at a specific line number without looping through every line in the file?

Comment: Easy. Just read from the start of the file stream, then count every linebreak until you've reached 9073244 linebreaks - that's where you start writing :)

Comment: @snakecharmerb that looks promising. But how do I index that particular line? Most examples are done with files that contain only a single line

Comment: Oh, I see you only have the line number :(

Comment: In the code, you _only_ write the bad line to the new file.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yeah I was looking at that too, but in the current code, nothing is replaced at all. I want to take the entire file and only replace that line I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linecache` access internally your file line by line, so in terms of speed, you gain nothing by using it (`linecache` will give you a performance advantage if you try to access many lines from many files repeatedly, which is not your use case). Therefore you will have to go line-by-line to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've a solution that doesn't require looping.
I just don't know if this fits your requirements. If you want to remove the line altogether, you would obviously not use "\n" but "".

```py
LINE_NUMBER = 1001
NEW_LINE = "\n"
NEW_LINE_2 = ""
NEW_LINE_3 = "".encode()

def init():
    with open("temp.txt", "w") as temp:
        temp.write("Foo\n" * 1000)
        temp.write("REPLACE ME!\n")
        temp.write("Bar\n" * 1000)
    #input("[PRESS ENTER TO OVERWRITE THE FILE]")
def test1():
    init()
    with open("temp.txt", "r+") as temp:
        lines = temp.readlines()
        lines[LINE_NUMBER - 1] = NEW_LINE
        temp.seek(0)
        temp.writelines(lines)
        temp.truncate()
def test2():
    init()
    with open("temp.txt", "r+") as temp:
        lines = temp.read().split("\n")
        lines[LINE_NUMBER - 1] = NEW_LINE_2
        temp.seek(0)
        temp.write("\n".join(lines))
        temp.truncate()
def test3():
    init()
    with open("temp.txt", "rb+") as temp:
        lines = temp.read().split(b"\n")
        lines[LINE_NUMBER - 1] = NEW_LINE_3
        temp.seek(0)
        temp.write(b"\n".join(lines))
        temp.truncate()
from timeit import repeat
loops = 300
count = 1
print(loops * min(repeat("test1()", globals=globals(), repeat=loops, number=count)))
print(loops * min(repeat("test2()", globals=globals(), repeat=loops, number=count)))
print(loops * min(repeat("test3()", globals=globals(), repeat=loops, number=count)))
```

```
0.9838907746598125
0.15912508824840188 # < Recommended
0.18560938769951463
```

After init:

```
<Foo> * 1000
REPLACE ME!
<Bar> * 1000
```

After test 1/2:

```
<Foo> * 1000

<Bar> * 1000
```

I've no idea why read bytes is slower

Comment: `readlines` read all the lines in the file one-by-one

Comment: well, the whole point of the question is "I have a huge file, can I find and replace a pattern in a line of the file without going through all the lines preceding it?"... The answer is "no", in fact, assuming the pattern only happens once, `readlines` is even worse, as it will go through the whole file (while hand-written code will only iterate until the ocurrence of the pattern)

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia, is it for speed or memory Reasons?

Comment: no idea - OP doesn't detail it. In any case, `readlines` reads all lines of the file into memory, so it's not advantageous neither for speed or memory. Better to iterate through the file (`for line in f`)

Comment: I was hoping to get faster code that was why I asked

Comment: @saQuist, I've three solutions, number 2 is the best.