# Python change headerrow of textfile (.csv)

Tags: python, header-files

I have a txt file where the headerrow is incorrect.  How do I replace the headerrow with the correct one?

```py
old_header = "1;2;3;4;5;"
new_header = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8"
```

If I read the file with I don't get the first line.

```py
    with open(full_path) as file:
        first_line = file.readline()
```

[image]

```
CompanyNumber;AccountingYear;Schema;RAT001;RAT002;RAT003;RAT004;RAT005;RAT006;RAT007;RAT008;RAT009;RAT010;RAT011;RAT012;RAT013;RAT014;RAT015;RAT016;RAT017;RAT018;RAT019;RAT020;RAT021;RAT101;RAT102;RAT103;RAT104;RAT105;RAT106;RAT107;RAT108;RAT109;RAT110;RAT111;RAT112;RAT113;RAT114;RAT115;RAT116;RAT117;RAT118;RAT119;RAT120;RAT121;RAT125;RAT127;RAT201;RAT202;RAT203;RAT204;RAT205;RAT206;RAT207;RAT208;RAT209;RAT210;RAT211;RAT212;RAT213;RAT214;RAT217;RAT218;RAT219;RAT220;RAT221
9999999999;2020;Abbreviated with capital;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-10.7;0.33;-1.57;-3.8;-3.74;-1.5;;;;;;;100;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
8888888888;2020;Full with capital;11.16;8.34;90.25;67804.74;80.92;87.52;3.97;0.16;15.22;20.41;12.65;9.48;1.67;2;;;4.82;91.32;61.21;8.94;17.06;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Red: headerrow where there needs to be added `;x1;x2;x3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search and replace a line in a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean by you don't get the first line? Did you try to print out `first_line` to see what it contains? Replacing contents of a file means either rewriting the file or using fileinput with the replace option.

Comment: @user56700 I get the firstline with data, not the headerrow

Comment: @RandomGuy: this replaces a line in the file not the first line.

Comment: @Tralala You need to provide an example of the contents of the file.

Comment: Please post text as *text*, not an image.  We're not going to manually type it in to try it.

Comment: Could you mention the file extension?

Comment: @Hamed_gibago It 's a csv-file.

Comment: just as an FYI, if you change the number of columns in the header, you also need to change the number of columns in each row

Comment: @EdoAkse: there is a problem with the columnheader, it only has 66 columns, and the data (some lines) had 99.  I tried changing it manually (header) and I can load the data in pandas.

Comment: I think the solution is add headers to and for other rows add empty values for these three headers: `;x1;x2;x3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the file, strip the end of line character, add the needed part to the first line, write new file (with new EOL characters)

```py
with open("data.csv") as infile:
    data = infile.read().splitlines()

data[0] = data[0] + ";x1;x2;x3"

with open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for line in data:
        outfile.write(line+"\n")
```