# Is there a way to remove a single line in Python without wasting resources?

Tags: python, performance, file, large-data, resource-management

I have a very large file stored as a `.txt`, which has a size of 13 GB. In the file, there are lines marked as `[Invalid]` in absolutely random places. Considering that the file is that huge, I don't think it'll be good to run the script on a limited testing machine with a slow old HDD.

The file I used for this looks similar to the sample provided below. I also tried playing around with `truncate()`, but that would only lead to removal of the last lines or getting the file cleared entirely (luckily I had a backup).

```
Vf1Ga0Qie6cxuc8o4cZK
XmQ71QRzm42Bju5DEGVn
[Invalid] diBWMYL67YfvawddJF3k
rjfUecVHkym7N0d5rJ4v
```

Perhaps Python has a more efficient way of removing specific lines? I tried googling the answer but I couldn't find anything like this, only little scripts that rewrite the whole file. For example:

```py
input_file = "badfile.txt"

with open(input_file, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# In my opinion, also can be optimized for a machine with limited RAM 
# by reading lines one-by-one

lines = [line for line in lines if "[Invalid]" not in line]

output_file = "badfile.txt"

with open(output_file, "w") as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Are you optimizing for disc access or memory? Because you write either. Optimizing for two things at once rarely works well. And do you run into any hard performance bottlenecks? Because running through 13 Gigs of text is still faster than waiting for an answer on SO :-)

Comment: @Friedrich
I'm optimizing for disk usage, RAM optimization is just an additional note for the code above. And I know that I could've simply left it do its thing, I just want to make sure there isn't a way to do that more efficiently I had no idea about.

Also, I don't face any bottlenecks, everything's pretty stable. Mostly the problem is with this HDD of mine because it has a very slow writing speed. Rewriting such a file will take around 29 hours.

Comment: If Python is not a requisite, you may want to do it using grep: `grep -v "Invalid" badfile.txt > goodfile.txt`

Comment: Logically you have to write to a new file but memory use can easily be restricted as the various responses are proposing. But that is a **very** slow write speed even for an old HDD. You could get a new one for very little or an even faster SSD at around $50 for 1 TB.

Comment: @triplee has closed this question by referencing a post that suggests reading the entire file into memory

Comment: @user19077881 Actually, this isn't really a computer I own, so, unfortunately I can't replace the HDD with a proper SSD. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart Sounds like a good idea, I might try it. I also thought about using `sed '/\[Invalid\]/d' badfile.txt > newfile.txt` as it works pretty well in such situations.

Comment: @Codist That's because there is no way to modify a line in a text file and not touch the rest. If you need that sort of versatility, use e.g. a database. But I'm repeating things you would already know if you actually read the duplicate.

Comment: @triplee I did read the so-called duplicate. The accepted answer in that post requires that the entire input file be read into memory which I infer from the original question to be a constraint. Maybe I've lost track of what the constraints really are

Comment: I'll say it again: There is no way you can obey that constraint; that's exactly what the duplicate already tells you.

Comment: Question is also answered on https://stackoverflow.com/q/39086/20851944

Comment: 29 hours to sequentially write 13 GB? That's ridiculous. There's something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to `fileinput()`, find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html):
This `inplace=True` reads your file and redirect the `print()` in the source file, be careful!

```
import fileinput

word = "[Invalid]"
with fileinput.input(files=('badfile.txt'), encoding="utf-8", inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if word not in line:
            print(line, end='')
```

Comment: You suggest redirecting stdout to the file that you're currently reading. Isn't that a recipe for disaster?

Comment: @Codist No; the `fileinput` module takes care to handle exactly this scenario with a useful, debugged, and battle-tested abstraction which hides the ugly and definitely nontrivial details behind the `inplace=True` keyword argument.